# I want to count coupon usage on my page.But it keeps updating whenever i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

**HERE IS THE CODE I'M USING TO UPDATE THE COUPON COUNT.**

```
 <div id="click" class="coupon-detail coupon-button-type">
                    <a  href="#" class="coupon-button coupon-code" data-aff-url="https://example.com">
                   <span class="code-text">CODE</span>
                  <span class="get-code">Get Code</span>
                    </a>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
                   </div>
                         <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="coupon-footer coupon-listing-footer">
            <ul class="clearfix">
               <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function(e) {
              $('#click').click(function(){
     <?php 
                   $update = "UPDATE coupon_stats SET today = today + 1";
                   $query_coupon = mysqli_query($con , $update)or die(mysqli_error($con));
                ?>
                     })
                    });
         </script>

          <?php
        $select = "SELECT * FROM coupon_stats";
        $query_select = mysqli_query($con,$select);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select);
        ?>
        <li><span><i class="wifi icon">  </i> <?php echo $data['today'].' Coupon Used'; ?>
        </span>
        </li>
```

but my coupon count is getting +1 whenever I refresh the page instead of clicking on the button.
I'm not getting an idea. What am I doing wrong? 
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding the difference between server-side and client-side code : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: `$update = "UPDATE coupon_stats SET today = today + 1";
                   $query_coupon = mysqli_query($con , $update)or die(mysqli_error($con));` <--- This code, is PHP and will execute on the server before the page is loaded, you cannot have it as part of a click function in Javascript as Javascript is executed on the client, after the page loads.

Comment: Use AJAX to send a request to a PHP file, and update it there.

Comment: @BarryThomas. I tried that. Still, something is not working. I put php code in another file and call that file using ajax method in coupon page. But coupon usage is not incrementing on click.

Comment: @BarryThomas. My problem is I have never worked with ajax before.

Comment: @CD001 My problem is I have never worked with ajax before

Comment: Can you post your updated code with your AJAX and your other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need.

We set data: 1 in the ajax request, so you can perform a check when the page loads `if(isset($_POST['data]))` on the process_request.php file.

```
<div id="click" class="coupon-detail coupon-button-type">
    <a  href="#" class="coupon-button coupon-code" data-aff-url="https://example.com">
        <span class="code-text">CODE</span>
        <span class="get-code">Get Code</span>
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="coupon-footer coupon-listing-footer">
    <ul class="clearfix">
    <?php

        $select = "SELECT * FROM coupon_stats";
        $query_select = mysqli_query($con,$select);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_select);
    ?>
    <li>
        <span>
            <i class="wifi icon"></i> <?php echo $data['today'].' Coupon Used'; ?>
        </span>
    </li>

<script>



    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#click').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : "process_request.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {data: 1},
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    //data - response from server
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {

                }
            });
        })
    });

</script>
```

In process_request.php

```
<?php 
    //Add db connection details
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $update = "UPDATE coupon_stats SET today = today + 1";
        $query_coupon = mysqli_query($con , $update)or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
?>
```

You can go further and add a response from process_request.php and then handle that in the success function of AJAX.

Comment: Thank you, Sir :). but something is wrong with my code. My coupon usage is not being updated.

Comment: Ok - well a bit of debugging should sort that. Echo $_POST['data'] on process_request.php to make sure it is not empty. If it is, then that is the issue, if it is not, then something is wrong with the sql query on porcess_request.php

Comment: I will send you code in morning tomorrow.So you can see what is wrong with it.